# Read the user input in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I'm experimenting around a custom Lisp evaluator (reading *Lisp in Small Pieces*) in CLJS with [Lumo](https://github.com/anmonteiro/lumo).
Is there a way to ask the user for a string and then process it? Like the shell has `read` or Python has `input`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use nodejs readline package:

```
(def readline (js/require "readline"))
(def rl (.createInterface readline #js {:input (.-stdin js/process) :output (.-stdout js/process)}))

(.question rl "ok?" pr)
```